# Shiny: observeEvent stuck on DTOutput

Tags: r, shiny

In the app below, I can switch back and forth between outputs generated by `shiny::plotOutput` and `shiny::dataTableOutput`. But when I select the option "DT", which generates a table using the `DT::DTOutput` function, the app gets stuck:

1. I can interact with the table (good)
2. Clicking "Load" does nothing (not good) even though it worked perfectly when non-DT output was selected before. Clicking "Load" should switch to selected output.

Is this a bug in DT? Is there a workaround?

UI:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("ui_select"),
  uiOutput("my_ui")
)
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$ui_select = renderUI({
    tagList(
      selectInput("selectVal", "Select value", choices = c("gg", "dt", "DT")),
      actionButton("loadVal", label = "Load")
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$loadVal, {

    val = isolate({ input$selectVal })

    output$my_output = switch(
      val,
      "gg" = renderPlot({ ggplot2::qplot(cyl, drat, data = mtcars) }),
      "dt" = renderDataTable({ mtcars[1:3, 1:3] }),
      "DT" = DT::renderDT({ mtcars[1:3, 1:3] })
    )

    output$my_ui = renderUI({
      switch(
        val,
        "gg" = plotOutput("my_output"),
        "dt" = dataTableOutput("my_output"),
        "DT" = DT::DTOutput("my_output")
      )
    })

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're essentially defining multiple elements with the same ID. That's invalid HTML, and is bound to result in undefined behaviour. Sometimes defining multiple inputs/outpust with identical IDs seems to work, but it should never be done.

Giving each output its own ID solves this.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$ui_select = renderUI({
        tagList(
            selectInput("selectVal", "Select value", choices = c("gg", "dt", "DT")),
            actionButton("loadVal", label = "Load")
        )
    })

    observeEvent(input$loadVal, {

        val = isolate({ input$selectVal })

        output$gg_output = renderPlot({ ggplot2::qplot(cyl, drat, data = mtcars) })
        output$dt_output = renderDataTable({ mtcars[1:3, 1:3] })
        output$DT_output = DT::renderDT({ mtcars[1:3, 1:3] })

        output$my_ui = renderUI({
            switch(
                val,
                "gg" = plotOutput("gg_output"),
                "dt" = dataTableOutput("dt_output"),
                "DT" = DT::DTOutput("DT_output")
            )
        })

    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Aha! So if I define two outputs with the same Id, I haven't overwritten the first one with the second one, but rather created two of them with the same Id? Let's say that it is convenient to keep reusing the same Id for the same of the argument. Is there a way to overwrite the first one?

Comment: And a related question: If I use increasing value of the `loadVal` from the action button to create unique IDs, am I creating a large number of HTML elements that will eventually slow down my application?

Comment: Technically I think you won't have multiple elements *at the same time* using the same ID but it will confuse shiny that there are multiple outputs being rendered with the same ID. To test out your later question, you can try using a loop to create 10,000 and see what happens :)

Answer (score 1):

Its generally not a good idea to render much inside the `observe` as a memory leak can occur. have a look at the example below with a bigger `diamonds` dataset from the `ggplot2` package.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("ui_select"),
  uiOutput("my_ui")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$ui_select = renderUI({
    tagList(
      selectInput("selectVal", "Select value", choices = c("gg", "dt", "DT")),
      actionButton("loadVal", label = "Load")
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$loadVal, {

    val = isolate({ input$selectVal })

    output$gg_output = renderPlot({ ggplot2::qplot(cyl, drat, data = mtcars) })
    output$dt_output = renderDataTable({ diamonds })
    output$DT_output = DT::renderDT({ diamonds })

    output$my_ui = renderUI({
      switch(
        val,
        "gg" = plotOutput("gg_output"),
        "dt" = dataTableOutput("dt_output"),
        "DT" = DT::DTOutput("DT_output")
      )
    })

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Also I dont think its very efficient to create objects all the time, its best to render them once and simply switch and show what is required.

**Proposed solution**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
outputs <- c("gg_output","dt_output","DT_output")

hideoutputs <- function(output_names){
  lapply(output_names, function(output_name){
    hide(output_name)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  uiOutput("ui_select"),
  plotOutput("gg_output"),
  dataTableOutput("dt_output"),
  DT::DTOutput("DT_output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  hideoutputs(outputs)
  v <- reactiveValues(selection = "None")

  output$ui_select <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      selectInput("selectVal", "Select value", choices = c("gg", "dt", "DT")),
      actionButton("loadVal", label = "Load")
    )
  })

  output$gg_output <- renderPlot({ 
    qplot(cyl, drat, data = mtcars) 
  })

  output$dt_output <- renderDataTable({ 
    diamonds 
  })

  output$DT_output <- DT::renderDT({ 
    diamonds 
  })

  observeEvent(input$loadVal, {

    if(v$selection == input$selectVal){
      return()
    }

    hideoutputs(outputs)
    switch(
      input$selectVal,
      "gg" = show("gg_output"),
      "dt" = show("dt_output"),
      "DT" = show("DT_output")
    )
    v$selection <- input$selectVal
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is insightful! I really should learn to use browser tools. A bit of context here (at the risk of going beyond the scope of the original question): What if a user chooses from a long list of available outputs, and will end up looking at a few of them in the course of the session. Wouldn't it be wasteful to pre-render all of them? What if there is 500 of them? (Let's say a large database of charts and tables in different UI configurations build up over time...)

Comment: For loads of them you probably need to use `renderUI` however you can then track and cache them as well